# Little-o in Tayloer Series

Tags: limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I have to expand $\arctan(x)$ up to $o(x^4)$ and I am having a problem in understanding how to reach $o(x^4)$ in a term.

The initial limit is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+\arctan(x)) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)-x}{x^4}$$

I started with expanding $\ln(1+X)$ where $X = \arctan(x)$, and then I started expanding $\arctan(x)$.

$$\ln(1+\arctan(x)) \sim \left(x - \dfrac{x^3}{3} + o(x^4)\right) - \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x - \dfrac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3)\right)^2 + \dfrac{1}{3}(x + o(x))^3 - \dfrac{1}{4}(x+o(x))^4$$

Now in the first two terms I am donw, since I can see $o(x^4)$. In the first term it's manifest and in the second term I appeal to little-o algebra such that being it a square of a three terms, like $(a+b+c)^2$ I will meet the term $2ac \equiv 2xo(x^3) = o(x^4)$.

I cannot figure out how to get an $o(x^4)$ instead in the third term.

$$(x + o(x))^3 = (x+o(x))\cdot (x+o(x))\cdot (x+o(x))$$

I also tried by incrasing with a term like

$$\left(x - \dfrac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3)\right)^3$$

But I cannot come to an $o(x^4)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to compute $\ln(1+\arctan x)$ up to $o(x^4)$ (or possibly $O(x^4)$)?

Comment: @J.G. Yes. THe original function is $\ln(1 + \arctan(x))$ but we only have to work with little-o algebra, so up to $o(x^4)$.

Comment: @J.G. Would it be correct if I expanded up to a term with $o(x^5)$ which then in comparison to all the other $o(x^4)$ parts, will be "neglected"?

Comment: @J.G. This is a part of a "bigger" limit, there I have a denominator which is $x^4$.

Comment: @J.G. Wait I don't need necessarily $o(x^4)$. I can write up to $o(x^5)$ since I know that $o(x^n) + o(x^m) = o(x^p)$ where $p$ is the min between $n$ and $m$.

Comment: To evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^4}$ you need to quote $f$ up to and including $O(x^4)$ terms, and can neglect any $o(x^4)$ terms in $f$.

Comment: @J.G. We cannot work with big O. We only can work with little o. I know it sounds stupid, but this is what our professor wants.

Comment: Does your professor expect you to write $\ln(1+\arctan x)+\frac12\ln(1+x^2)-x\in-\frac16x^4+o(x^4)$, or the less pedantic $\ln(1+\arctan x)+\frac12\ln(1+x^2)-x=-\frac16x^4+o(x^4)$?

Comment: @J.G. For every function, we have to expand to the "useful" order, which here is $o(x^4)$. So $\ln(1+x^2) = x^2 - x^4/2 + o(x^4)$ and so on. I managed to understand how to deal with the arctangent part though: the term I was asking for, that is the third power of arctangent, can be written as

$$\arctan^3(x) \approx (x + o(x^2))^2$$

Me stopping to the second order. There is no second order (second power) in the arctangent, but I understood I can do it the same. Like if I did $\sin(x) \approx x + o(x^2)$.

Comment: You need to use $\arctan x\in x-\frac13x^3+o(x^4)$ to do all these calculations correctly.

Comment: Okk! I tried and indeed I worked out the answer. I perhaps lost myself in a glass of water before. Thank you so much!